# What will be the correct way to connect to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js

i am confusing when is the time to connect mysql.
should i connect the mysql when the program start?

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(...);
router.get('/', (ctx, next) => {
     connection.query('SELECT 1', function (error, results, fields) {
     if (error) throw error;
     // connected!
     });
});
```

or like this

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
router.get('/', (ctx, next) => {
         var connection = mysql.createConnection(...);
         connection.query('SELECT 1', function (error, results, fields) {
         if (error) throw error;
         // connected!
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not connect it when the program starts. On the one hand you program will fail if the connection times out, and you want to use a separate db connection for each connection of a client.

So if you have to decide between the two solutions you provided then you should take the second one. But you should close the connection using `connection.end();`

Alternatively you can use a connection pool:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createPool(...);

router.get('/', (ctx, next) => {
  connection.query('SELECT 1', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
    // connected!
  });
});
```

If you want to share one db connection for all routes you could add a middle ware like this:

```
router.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  await new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        ctx.dbConnection = connection
        resolve()
      }
    })
  })
  await next()
  ctx.dbConnection.release()
})

router.get('/', (ctx, next) => {
  connection.query('SELECT 1', function (error, results, fields) {
     if (error) throw error;
     // connected!
  });
});
```

And I would suggest to switch to a promise based version of mysql.